# совместная работа aiogram и socketio

Tags: python, aiogram, socket.io

Есть обычный бот на aiogram. Пишу  связку магазин(сайт) + магазин(бот) + сервер

Возникла проблема с доставкой сообщений о заказе менеджеру.
План такой: подписываемся на сообщения от сервера и ждём от него ответа о новых заказах.

Но я никак не могу понять как мне сделать ожидание этих сообщений в фоне.
код бота: и он по понятным причинам не работает. Ибо начинает крутиться в asyncio.wait()

```
async def main():
    await sio.connect(SERVER_HOST)
    await sio.wait() # как передать процесс => executor.start_polling


if __name__ == '__main__':

    asyncio.run(main())
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=on_startup, skip_updates=True)
```

Нашел похожий вопрос. но ничего толкового от туда не достал.
[Python интеграция aiogram + Socket.IO Server](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483094/python-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-aiogram-socket-io-server)

если вдруг не понятно что я хочу.
заказ можно сделать как с сайта так и с бота. менеджер сидит преимущественно в тг. и сообщения должны идти туда.

я только начал изучать сокеты, так что, пожалуйста, сильно палками не бейте.

Comment: Может есть какой другой способ решить данную проблему?
Не создавать отдельный коннект под сокет, а как то иначе?

Мне всего лишь нужно проверять, есть ли в базе новые заказы.
Но делать обычные get запросы каждую минуту считаю чем то ужасным.